# Magento 2 upgrade steps : 2.3.6 to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I am working on creating steps to upgrade
Magento ver. 2.3.6 EE to Magento ver. 2.4.3 EE (latest version)

Which are the steps required to upgrade the magento ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Please check here https://techurbane.com/how-to-migrate-magento-2-3-to-2-4/

Answer (score 1):

source https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/upgrade-magento-version-2-3-x-2-4-0/

## Preparing Your Site for Upgrade

1. Make sure your server is configured to work with PHP 7.4. Magento
   2.4.3 officially support only PHP 7.4. Though you can install Magento
   2.4.3 with PHP 7.3 but it is not tested. So it is
   recommended to use PHP 7.4 with Magento 2.4.3. You can check your
   PHP version by running below command php -v
2. Make sure your composer is pointing to correct PHP version 7.4. You
   can check your composer’s PHP version by running below command
   composer -vvv about
3. Make sure your server has installed and configured Elasticsearch
   7.6.x. Magento 2.4.3 does not support MySQL as a catalog search engine. You can check your Elasticsearch version by running below command

   ```
   curl -XGET ‘http://localhost:9200’
   # OR
   curl -XGET ‘http://YOURDOMAIN:9200’
   ```
4. Take a code and database backup. Many developers are already
   managing their code in git. For them, an only database backup is
   important as they can revert the code from git if the upgrade goes
   wrong.

## Upgrade Magento Version from 2.3.X to 2.4.3

Step 1: If you are directly performing the upgrade on your live site then first put your site into maintenance mode by running below command.

```
 php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Step 2: If you are performing the upgrade on your local system then you can skip step 1 and start with step 2.
Take a backup of the composer.json

```
 cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

Step 3: Install the Composer update plugin

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
 
composer update
```

Step 4: Update composer.json file with latest version. In our case, it is Magento Version 2.4.3. Navigate to your Magento 2 installation root path and run below command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
```

Step 5: Run below command

```
composer update
```

This command will take some time to finish. This command will actually download all the required packages and upgrade your Magento version from 2.3.x to 2.4.3. After this command finish, run below commands

Step 6: Clear cache and regenerate code.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean 
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/* 
rm -rf generated/code/* 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento setup:di:compile  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Step 7: Disable maintenance mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Note: Remove update directory from your root folder as update directory is not a part of Magento 2.4

For more see official https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Accept if helps

Comment: When should i remove the update directory ?

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer, can you please add answer source link also ?

Comment: Also do i need to have exact version of softwares mentioned here for 2.4.3 magento version
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html ?

Comment: yes you need exact versions

Comment: composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update

I am using magento EE version & also going to upgrade EE version of magento

Comment: exact version for all softwares ?

Comment: yes you need exact versions those which are you using

Comment: ok update answer to this - composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update

Comment: is Install the Composer update plugin step is required ?

Comment: you need to update the composer as well